# Packages `tikz` and `pgfmath` missing in my `MikTex 2.9` distribution?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, miktex2.9

(1) My `MikTeX 2.9` package manager does not list the `tikz` package. Yet, `\usepackage{tikz}` will compile without error, and invoking  `\usetikzlibrary`will flag an `!Undefined control sequence` error unless `tikz` is present.
(2) Neither does my `MikTeX 2.9` distribution list the `pgfmath` package, yet `\usepackage{pgfmath}` does not flag a `!LaTeX Error: file pgfmath.sty not found` compilation  error.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 15 October 2017
%=======================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}
This is an MWE!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you disabled the installation on-fly feature? This will take care of any missing packages. `MikTex Setting->MikTex Options->Genereal/Package Installation`.

Comment: @CroCo It's been enabled all along. But my question is primarily why don't `tikz` and `pgfmath` show up in the `package manager` listing, regardless of whether installed or not? Evidently they are present in some sense as neither `\usepackage{tikz}` nor `\usepackage{pgfmath}` flag an error at compilation - like `\usepackage{tokz}` certainly will!

Comment: Just read in `Tantau's PGF TikZ Manual` that `pgfmath` is loaded automatically when `pgf` is loaded (Section 88.1), and that `pgf` is loaded when `tikz` is loaded (Section 12.1), so what remains of my question is wondering why `tikz` does not show up in the `MikTeX 2.9 Package Manager` listing.

Comment: Not really you can use pgfmath standalone. Something went wrong with the package database probably.

Comment: The miktex package is called `pgf` and contains tons of files starting with `pgf` and also a few starting with `tikz`.

Comment: I can assure you they, but there are so many files that probably you missed them. They're located in `texmf\tex\latex\pdf`frontendlayer` and `texmf\tex\latex\pgf\math` respectively.

Comment: There are two different locations sty files are stored using Windows: admin files are typically stored in `\program files\MikTeX 2.9\tex\` while on-the-fly files are stored in `\users\...\AppData\Roaming\MikTeX\2.9\tex\`

Comment: ... in summary then, will invoking `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\usepackage{pgf}` , `\usepackage{pgfmath}`and the gaggle of `\usetikzlibrary{..., ...,   }` as required, ensure I have all the files at my disposal?

Comment: Well, not really, but if those `\usepackage` and `\usetikzlibrary` calls works without error that means that you *do* have the necessary files.  (By the way, if you have `\usepackage{tikz}` you don't need `\usepackage{pgf,pgfmath}`, as `tikz` loads the last two.)